# Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key 'textAlign' supplied to 'View'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new with react-native, and I got this warning:

```
 Warning:Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key 'textAlign' supplied to 'View'
 Bad object:{
             "textAlign":"center",....}
```

what might be the problem, the app isn't crash but I just wondering how to solve this warning...

this is the code after stack trace:

```
 <View style={styles.botTextView}>
 .....
 botTextView: {
textAlign: 'center',
position: 'relative',
flex: 1,
top: 8,
flexDirection: 'column',
alignItems: 'center',
alignSelf: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check React-native documentation : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props

You will see that the view component does not have a textAlign style prop.
Consider using Text component if you want to display text on a react-native app.

Edit :

Your text was centered because of those two lines:

```
alignItems: 'center'       //centers the View's children on the y-axis
justifyContent: 'center'   //centers the View's children on the x-axis
```

But if you want to center a text on the x-axis without centering other children you can try the following:

```
<View style={styles.botView}>
    <Text style={styles.botText}>
        //Text
    </Text>
</View>
.....
botView: {
    position: 'relative',
    flex: 1,
    top: 8,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
botText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
},
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer... if ill use text element it will have the same effect as text align? by the way, right now text align doesnt do anything in this style?

Comment: You will have to use a `<Text>` element to display text. Put the Text inside the View Container

Comment: @R.Duteil so in my case I can just delete the textAlign line because the other two lines I have. right?

Comment: Removing this line will stop the warning, but considering you are still learning, you should probably use the right component to achieve your goal, I.E. the Text one